# play icon youtube video div overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, overlay

I have an image nav but the client wants to add a video icon via the product description.

[image]

When the user clicks on the video icon it should overlay the youtube video on top of the main product image. Kinda like hiding it and just showing the video.

I cannot find any jquery plugin that can do this?

Here is some example markup which i have created, when you click play on the icon i want the youtube video to be played inside of the red box on top of the image.

**Look at my example:** http://jsfiddle.net/mC5c3/4/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">

<div class="product-image">
<img src="http://www.skriftlig.com/konfliktmegling/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/Photoxpress_2658886-480x220.jpg" alt="http://www.skriftlig.com/konfliktmegling/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/Photoxpress_2658886-480x220.jpg">
</div>

    <div class="image-nav">
    </div>

    <div class="icon">
        &nbsp
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.container
{
    margin:10px 10px auto;
    border:1px solid orange;
}

div.product-image
{
    height:220px;
    width:480px;
    border:1px solid red;  
    margin:30px;        
}

div.image-nav
{
    border:1px solid black;
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
    margin:30px;
}

div.icon
{
background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsQik.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 50px;
    left: 540px;
    position: relative;
    top: -104px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

**edit:**

1. It should be based on the icon click.
2. and show and hide based on the click of the icon.
3. The video needs to be embeded in the icon div so the client can change the video.

**I added a click event and resized the video**

```
var $video=$('<iframe width="480" height="220" src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/jvTv_oatLA0?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
var $productImage=$('.product-image');
var $icon=$('.icon');
$icon.on('click',function()
{
    $('.product-image').append($video);
});
```

​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $icon=$('.icon');
var $video=$('.product-image iframe');
$icon.on('click',function()
{
    $video.toggle();//Shows the video if hidden, hides the video if visible.
});
```

Comment: It should be based on the icon click... Thanks for this.

Comment: The video needs to be embeded in the icon div so the client can change the video.

Comment: It's easy to adapt that to match your requirements. Just change the on click handler to the icon and append the video to a different parent. If you want to toggle show/hide, add the iframe in HTML and set it's display to `none`. Then on click call `toggle()`.

Comment: I have added the iframe to the HTML markup , just need to do the show hide now.

Comment: I don't see the iframe in the markup. What is it that you need exactly? The user clicks the icon div (by the way you don't need `&nbsp;`) then the video gets appended to the `.product-image` div. What do you want different?

Comment: Changed the answer. Is that what you need?

Comment: click on play, video shows up in the red box, click on play again and the video is gone but the image should remain there: http://jsfiddle.net/mC5c3/12/

Comment: Move the `iframe` inside the `.product-image` then. I updated the code for `$video`.

Comment: You need to set `position:relative` on the `.product-image` div, you need to position the `iframe` absolutely to be over the image as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using you tube api:

```
function play() {
  if (ytplayer) {
    ytplayer.playVideo();
  }
}
```

Read You tube API reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=fr-FR#onYouTubePlayerReady